# .Net SDK problem, which way to go?

Tags: c#, .net, sdk

We're writing an SDK for a CAD program and have run into a slight disagreement regarding a specific type of function (not just disagreement between different people, also disagreement between my two brain-halves).

Imagine there's a lot of classes for specific curve types (ellipse, circle, arc, line, bezier etc.). All of these classes can be represented by a Nurbs curve. So should we put the Circle->Nurbs function on Circle:

```
public NurbsCurve Circle.ToNurbsCurve()
{
  // Return a circular NurbsCurve or null if the Circle is invalid.
}
```

or should it be a static on NurbsCurve:

```
public static NurbsCurve NurbsCurve.CreateFromCircle(Circle)
{
  // Return a circular NurbsCurve or null if the Circle is invalid.
}
```

Comment: One option would be extension methods.  `public static NurbsCurve ToNurbs(this Circle circle) {}`

Comment: @Chris, that wouldn't really make sense here... it is the Circle that knows how it should be converter to a NurbsCurve, not the NurbsCurve class. Extension methods are a cool feature, but many people (including me) overuse them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'd go for the first (e.g. on the shape classes, maybe even with a common base class or interface like `IConvertibleToNurbsCurve`), because this makes it easier if you add other shapes later which are also convertible to a `NurbsCurve`.

The `NurbsCurve` seems to be less specialized and therefore should not "know" about the more specialized types IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in the `Circle` class, because it's the one that knows how it should be converted to a `NurbsCurve`. The `NurbsCurve` class isn't supposed to know about all specific types of curve. That way, if you create a new type of curve, you won't have to modify the `NurbsCurve` class.

BTW, I suggest you declare the `ToNurbsCurve` method in an interface implemented by all curves (or declare it virtual in an abstract base class)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Regarding the Interface comment, we unfortunately have many different ToXxxx() functions so using interfaces for all of them would become somewhat unwieldy.